# PHPMailer, не приходят письма только на gmail

Tags: php

работаю с phpmailer, приходят письма и на yandex и mail почту, но НА GMAIL ПРОСТО НЕ ДОХОДЯТ!!!

Код:

```
    require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    require_once('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');
    require_once('phpmailer/class.pop3.php');
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Username = '***';             
    $mail->Password = '***';
    $mail->setFrom('angelsgfe.site@gmail.com', '');  
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, 'Information');
    $mail->isHTML(true);  

    $mail->Subject = 'Confirm email for review';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Please, confirm you email. Any questions? Please reply to this email!';
    $mail->msgHTML("<html><body>
    <h3><bold>Hello!</p>
                </html></body>");
    $mail->send();


    header('Location: /email.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

При использование smtp сервер от google нужно настройках аккаунта в разделе безопасность создать пароль приложения и уже созданный пароль использовать для подключения